# How do you say "like when you" or "the way you" in Japanese?

Tags: grammar, translation, slang, english-to-japanese

So basically, how do you say something like "talk to the boss the way you talk to your father!" You know, with a threatening tone.

Comment: you could try attempting something based on these examples and then more people would be inclined to give support:  http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%22the+way+you%22

Comment: The vast majority of Japanese speak to their bosses MUCH more politely than when they speak to their fathers.  So, saying "Talk to the boss the way you talk to your father!" is a very strange kind of threat in Japanese culture because you are, in effect, threatenng someone to speak to his boss very informally.

Comment: Oh... then how about "Talk to the boss the way you talk to your client!"... maybe??

Comment: haha yeah i know that, Japanese people speak informally with their families and formally at work but what i gave was just a random example. All i wanted to know was how to say "the way you"

Comment: i was halfway to writing an answer and then I wondered --  is there a way to express this using まま?

Answer (score 4):

How about...
~~する(とき)みたいな(しゃべり)かたをする, ~~するような(口のきき)かたをする, or ~~する(とき)みたいに~~する?